# VBS Tells me object doesn't support this property

Tags: vbscript, create-directory

I seriously don't know what's wrong, can anyone help:

```
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, objNewFolder

' Create the file system object/Assing the system object to a variable 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Get the folder we want to copy files from 
Set objFSO = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Test")

' Create a new folder called Test2 
Set objNewFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\Test\Test2")

' For each file in the folder, copy the file to the destination 
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files 
    objFile.Copy "C:\Test2" 
Next
```

It tells me that:

> vbs object doesn't support this property or method: 'CreateFolder'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are **reassigning** `objFSO` to become the `Folder` object returned here:

```
Set objFSO = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Test")
```

After this line, `objFSO` is no longer a `Scripting.FileSystemObject`, its a `Scripting.Folder` object.  You need to change your code to this:

```
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Test")
```